# Adding scores from separate queries in Neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, aggregate, graph-databases

Say I have two tables as results of two separate Cypher queries:

First table:

`login`                    `score`

`abc`                      `10`

`def`                      `20`

And second table:

`login`                    `score`

`abc`                      `50`

`ghi`                      `100`

I need a table in which the scores for the logins that exist in both tables are summed, and for other logins, they are listed with the single score available for them.

`login`                    `score`

`abc`                      `60`

`def`                      `20`

`ghi`                      `100`

Can you help with a Cypher query for this? What if I want to apply a custom aggregate function instead of simple summation?

Comment: How are you making these two queries? Are you using a `UNION`?

Comment: Since there is no such thing as a "table" in neo4j, by "table" do you actually mean "Cypher query result rows"? Also, please show your existing Cypher queries.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be super efficient if you have a large dataset, but something like the following will do the trick :

```
MATCH (c:Choice)
WITH collect(c.login) AS cset
MATCH (t:Thing)
WHERE NOT t.login IN cset
RETURN t.login AS login, t.score AS score

UNION ALL

MATCH (t:Thing)
WITH collect(t.login) AS tset
MATCH (c:Choice)
WHERE NOT c.login IN tset
RETURN c.login AS login, c.score AS score

UNION ALL

MATCH (c:Choice),(t:Thing {login: c.login})
RETURN c.login AS login, c.score + t.score AS score;
```

There may be more efficient ways to do this, but

1. First part gets you the scores for logins only in the Thing-nodes
2. Second part gets you the scores for logins only in the Choice-nodes
3. Third part sums the scores for logins present in both node types.
4. UNIONs link it all together.

Hope this helps,
Tom